# Lines shapefile plotted as polygons

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to import an SHP file containing the official map of rural bus routes in Ireland (https://www.transportforireland.ie/transitData/Rural_Transport_Services.zip). The file loads without errors but instead of expected lines qGIS plots strange polygons (see image) which by no means represent public transport routes. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I get the same result - you may want to contact the dataprovider and ask why they are polygons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like a line shapefile being misinterpreted.  The boundaries are not the roads.  Instead it looks like a service district map -- polygons around the bus routes representing areas from which one could reasonably catch a bus.

[image]